# Make an object only visible from a certain angle?

Tags: camera

I am modeling a cartoon character with a mouth that is designed to only be displayed on a single cheek, not in the middle. Its parent is a head mesh. I made two copies of the mouth: one on the left cheek of the head, the other on the right. I am wondering if there is any way to make the mouth on the side of the head that the camera is not primarily facing disappear? (i.e: if the camera is directed to the *left* side of the head, then the *left* mouth is visible, but the *right* one is not, and vice-versa.)

Because the camera is primarily facing the *left* side of the model, I need the *right* mouth (higlighted) to disappear.

[image]

I am using Blender Internal.

Blend file: [Blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlq27gsyw92f9jg/Newest%20Sonic%20-%20Mouth%20Test.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Welcome to BSE, is it possible to attach screen shots? And upload your .blend file?

Comment: Sure, fixed the OP.

Comment: Do you want this to be automatic or using a switch would be fine?

Comment: If it could be automatic, that would be great because I am planning on rendering in 8 angles / 8 different cameras around this. But if a swith would be easier, I'll take it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is using a Light Path node, just like Todd just said, but I'm using a different approach and a different node factor, since according to attached images, this has to happen while both mouths would be visible from a 3/4 angle:
1- Create a plane to go directly in the center of your character, The cube in the image here represents your character's head, the two spheres represent the mouth.
[image]
2- Assign a simple transparent material to the plane.
3- Mix a transparent shader to the material of the mouths (the spheres in this example), add a Light Path node, Add node>Input>Light Path, use the Transparent depth as a factor. This will make the object that this material assigned to, disappears when it falls behind an object with a transparent material, which is the plane here. Check the image below.
[image]
That's it check the animated GIF below to see how this will work, no need to say that from a front view, both of the mouths will show, so you can extrude the far edge of the transparent plane to the left or right to solve that issue.
[image]

Comment: Is there no way to do this in Blender Internal? If not, I can manage the switch from Internal to Cycles.

Comment: I know next to nothing about BI but I think this doable using a script

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by mixing your color shader with a transparent shader with the factor coming from a Camer Light Path node.

In the example below I've got a Red Cube with a Green Circle on opposite sides. There is a mirror surface behind the cube so we can see the back of the cube. Initially both side show the green circle.

When I update the green material to include the transparent shader with the camera light path node, you can see that only the circle that faces the camera shows. You can check the back circle by viewing the mirrored surface.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that this is not a complete answer due to the fact that you can see the part of the face where the other mouth should be. I'll update it shortly.